# Is the topology generated by a union of an increasing chain of metrizable topologies metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $S = \{\mathcal{T}_i \subset \mathcal{P}(X) : i \in I\}$ be metrizable topologies on $X$, where $I$ is a linearly ordered set, and $\mathcal{T}_i \subset \mathcal{T}_j$ whenever $i \leq j$; i.e. $\mathcal{T}_i$ are increasing.

Is the topology generated by $\bigcup S$ metrizable?

Comment: This sounds interesting but without some more context or discussion I feel like it’s asking to get closed

Comment: @MW Why would it get closed?

Comment: They have some kind of policy where they tend to close things that are just short statements of problems without either motivation, or discussion of what you've done to try to solve it, or something more than just "Here's the problem, what's the answer?".  I'm not saying I agree with the policy but I've seen them enforcing it a fair amount.

Comment: @MW Ok, thanks for clarifying. I'm a researcher, and sometimes my questions are like this. I get here when I get too frustrated on thinking of some problem. I try to include what I have tried, but this time there was not much to include.

Comment: Gotcha.  It's probably fine, in theory the target is more "lazy undergraduate who wants the internet to do their homework", I'm just a little jaded cause I've answered a few of what I thought were genuinely interesting ones and then had them closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Counterexample.** Let $X=\omega$. Construct a transfinite sequence of sets $S_\alpha\subseteq\omega$ ($\alpha\lt\omega_1$) so that
$$\alpha\lt\beta\lt\omega_1\implies|S_\beta\setminus S_\alpha|\lt\aleph_0=|S_\alpha\setminus S_\beta|.$$
Moreover, we can assume that $0\in S_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$, and $n\notin S_n$ for $1\le n\lt\omega$.

Let $I=[\omega,\omega_1)=\{\alpha:\omega\le\alpha\lt\omega_1\}$, and for each $\alpha\in I$ let $\tau_\alpha$ be the topology on $\omega$ generated by the sets $\{n\}$ ($1\le n\lt\omega$) and the sets $S_\nu$ ($0\le\nu\lt\alpha$).

For $\alpha\in I$ the topology $\tau_\alpha$ is metrizable by Urysohn's metrizaton theorem, since it is second countable, Hausdorff, and regular, even zero-dimensional. On the other hand, the topology generated by $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}\tau_\alpha$ is not metrizable or even first countable.

**P.S.** Suppose $\omega\le\gamma\lt\omega_1$ and suppose you have already constructed infinite sets $S_\alpha\subseteq\omega$ ($\alpha\lt\gamma$) so that
$$\alpha\lt\beta\lt\gamma\implies|S_\beta\setminus S_\alpha|\lt\aleph_0=|S_\alpha\setminus S_\beta|.$$
It follows that any intersection of finitely many sets $S_\alpha$ ($\alpha\lt\gamma$) is infinite. Rearrange the sets in a sequence of length $\omega$:
$$\{S_\alpha:\alpha\lt\gamma\}=\{T_n:n\lt\omega\}.$$
Choose elements $t_1\lt t_2\lt t_3\lt\cdots$ so that $t_n\in T_1\cap T_2\cap\cdots\cap T_n$, and let $S_\gamma=\{t_2,t_4,t_6,\dots\}$. Then
$$|S_\gamma\setminus S_\alpha|\lt\aleph_0=|S_\alpha\setminus S_\gamma|$$
for all $\alpha\lt\gamma$.

Comment: How do I find such a sequence?

Comment: @kaba I've edited my answer to include this construction.

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty great. Makes me wonder how you came up with all this. I guess you have worked out some similar looking problems before.

Comment: @kaba I believe this sort of construction is classical, going back at least to Hausdorff.

Comment: So what would be another context where you have seen this kind of construction?

Comment: @kaba I'm sorry, I don't remember very well. But see "Another variation introduced by Hausdorff (1936)" in the Wikipedia page about [Hausdorff gaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_gap) for something similar, I think. Unfortunately Hausdorff's 1936 paper is in German so it would be hard reading for me.

Comment: Yep that seems similar. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Let $(X,T)$ be any completely regular space such that there exists $T_0\subseteq T$ which is metrizable.  If it were true that the topology generated by a chain of metrizable topologies is always metrizable, then by Zorn's lemma there would exist a maximal metrizable topology $T_1\subseteq T$.  This $T_1$ would have to be equal to $T$, since if it were not, then by complete regularity of $T$ there would be a $T$-continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ that is not $T_1$-continuous and then you could consider the induced topology on the graph of $f$ in $X\times\mathbb{R}$ (where the first coordinate is topologized with $T_1$) to contradict the maximality of $T_1$.

So, if the statement you were asking for were true, then every completely regular topology that contains a metrizable topology would be metrizable.  Counterexamples to this are easy to find; for instance, the Sorgenfrey line is completely regular and not metrizable but its topology contains the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.  Or, to generalize the example in bof's answer, you can take any non-metrizable completely regular topology on a countable set and it will contain the metrizable topology generated by a countable family of real-valued functions that separate its points.

Comment: Thanks! I don't follow the last statement of the first paragraph. How should I consider the induced topology on the graph of $f$? Is there a contradiction somewhere?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez No, it's arbitrary chains. I don't think I mention sequences anywhere.

Comment: Oh, actually I do in the title. That's a mistake. Fixed it.

Comment: @Eric I'm still not seeing the contradiction :( Somehow there is a metrizable topology finer than $T_1$, but which one?

Comment: @kaba: The topology on the graph of $f$ (identified with $X$).  If you like, it's the topology generated by $T_1$ together with $f^{-1}(U)$ for each open $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.  (But the point of looking at the graph is to see that this topology is metrizable since $X\times\mathbb{R}$ is.)

Comment: @EricWofsey Let's call the finer metrizable topology $T_2$ and topology on reals $T_{\mathbb{R}}$. Then $f$ is $(T_2, T_{\mathbb{R}})$-continuous by construction. By continuity, $T_2 \approx (T_2 \times T_{\mathbb{R}})|G(f)$. Here $\times$ denotes the product topology, $\approx$ a homeomorphism, $|$ restriction to subspace topology, and $G(f)$ graph of $f$. Are you claiming $(T_1 \times T_{\mathbb{R}})|G(f) \approx T_2$?

Comment: @kaba: That's correct.  This is essentially immediate from the definitions when you write down what a basic open set of $(T_1 \times T_{\mathbb{R}})|G(f)$ is (it's the intersection of an element of $T_1$ with a set of the form $f^{-1}(U)$).

Comment: @EricWofsey I think you mean the supposed $(T_2, (T_1 \times T_{\mathbb{R}})|G[f])$-homeomorphism is $g : X \to G(f)$ defined by $g(x) = (x, f(x))$? Then $g$ is $(T_2, (T_1 \times T_{\mathbb{R}})|G(f))$-continuous, since $g^{-1}((U \times V) \cap G(f)) = U \cap f^{-1}(V) \in T_2$ for each $U \in T_1$ and $V \in T_{\mathbb{R}}$. Also $g$ is invertible. The problem though is that $g^{-1}$ does not seem to be $((T_1 \times T_{\mathbb{R}})|G(f), T_2)$-continuous, since there exists $U \in T_2 \setminus T_1$, and $(g^{-1})^{-1}(U) = g(U) = (U \times \mathbb{R}) \cap G(f)$.

Comment: @kaba: But $T_2$ is generated by $T_1$ and sets of the form $f^{-1}(U)$, so it suffices to check continuity of $g$ on sets of that form.  For elements of $T_1$ this is trivial and $(g^{-1})^{-1}(f^{-1}(U))$ is just $(X\times U)\cap G(f)$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, I think you are correct. Many thanks.